# Nested loop doesn't re-iterate

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

As a means to work on my python, I am trying to create an algorithm that solves word ladder puzzles - [see here for more info on how these work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_ladder)

[You can download the csv containing an english dictionary from here.](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/raw/master/words_alpha.txt)

This is where I have reached with the code:

```
import pandas as pd

alphabet = {0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'d', 4:'e', 5:'f', 6:'7', 7:'h', 8:'i', 9:'j', 10:'k', 11:'l', 12:'m', 13:'n', 14:'o', 15:'p', 16:'q', 17:'r', 18:'s', 19:'t', 20:'u', 21:'v', 22:'w', 23:'x', 24:'y', 25:'z'}

english = pd.read_csv('english.csv')
temp = [0, 1, 4, 19]
temp_alpha = ['a', 'b', 'e', 't']
target = tuple([2, 0, 18, 4])
original = tuple(temp)
solution = []

#loop to find solution starts here:

#builds in dictionary and false matches

if len(original) != len(target):
    print('Error: arguments must be same length')
elif len(original) == len(target):
    print('Here is your solution')
    while original != target:
        for i, v in enumerate(original):
            temp[i] = target[i]
            for j, k in enumerate(temp):
                temp_alpha[j] = alphabet[k]
                temp_alpha = ''.join(temp_alpha)
                for item in english.itertuples():
                    print(item) #to help diagnose errors
                    while temp_alpha < item[1]:
                        if temp_alpha in item[1]:
                            solution = temp_alpha
                        else:
                            temp[i] = original[i]
```

The code does great on the first letter, but, rather than go back to the second letter, it breaks at the end after iterating through the pd dataframe containing the english dictionary.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I read somewhere that if the level of nesting gets beyond 5, there's an issue with your approach (it's for sure a rule-of-thumb). You have 7 levels, plus an indentation error after `print(item)`. This code is very difficult to follow through to the most nested levels.

Comment: Thanks, just fixed the indentation issue. That's a helpful tip.

Comment: I can't find the english.csv in the repo you posted. Also, which letter gets replaced in the first iteration? Reading your code, I believe there's a couple of problems.
1.  Your code will never leave the while loop in its current form (you never modify 'original')
2. You join temp_alpha into a string, but never revert/reset it to a list.
If you provide your code in a completely reproducible form, I'll gladly try to help you :)

Comment: thanks @PejoPhylo. I posted a link to the csv above - sorry i couldn't think of a way to simplify that piece of the problem. The first letter in the starting 'word' (converted to integers) in the first iteration etc.

Comment: @OlliePerkins I'm sorry, but I really cannot find a csv in the repo you have linked to..

Comment: When you find yourself writing deeply nested code that does sort of the same thing at each level, it can probably be simplified (and generalized to an arbitrary depth) by writing a generator function.